# How to make the list to a table using robot framework

Tags: python, robotframework, rpa

```
    OUTLOOK.Open Application
    ${emails}=  Get Emails
    Log List    ${emails}

    @{filtered_emails}    Filter Emails    ${emails}
    ${lastest_email}    Get From List    ${filtered_emails}    -1
    Log    ${lastest_email}[Body]
    Set Task Variable    ${latest_body}    ${lastest_email}[Body]
    Log    ${latest_body}
    ${specific_text}=    Extract Specific Text    ${latest_body}
    Log    ${specific_text}
    Log To Console   ${specific_text}
    Log List    ${specific_text}
    ${test}    Get From List    ${specific_text}    0
```

By implementing the code above, what i got from Log List ${specific_text} is:
List length is 18 and it contains following items:
0: 025-DT-S24255
1: TCNU3848789
2: 025-DT-S24245
3: EITU9083782
4: 025-DT-S24247
5: EMCU8601448
6: 025-DT-S24251
7: MAGU5370276
8: 025-DT-S24253
9: EGSU9025768
10: 025-DT-S24257
11: EITU9071890
12: 025-DT-S24259
13: EMCU8242570
14: 025-DT-S24249
15: TLLU4852866
16: 025-DT-S24317
17: TLLU7650426

Based on the list above, i want the even index in the list store under a new table’s first column, while the odd index in the list store under a table’s second column, how can i do by using robocorp?